# add user_defiened function to DB2

Tags: db2

How can I add user defiened function to DB2 (SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)?
I want to add a new function like this:

```
SELECT myFunc (current timestamp) FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Do I need authorization to add new functions to DB2?

Answer (score 1):

To create a function, use the `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax. There are different types of functions that are possible, so you need to **study** the docs and understand your requirements - for example, internal functions, external functions, table functions, compiled/inlined functions.

The details vary with the **platform** of the Db2 server i.e. for Z/OS mainframe,  for i-series, or for linux/unix/windows/cloud,  and vary with the choice of implementation language.

Usually the authorization has to include one or more of CREATEIN on the schema, SYSADM/STSCTRL, DBADM etc, depending on the platform and the chosen implementation.